# WCF basichttpbinding netTcpBinding routing

Tags: wcf

I have created a WCF routing service. This service uses basicHTTPBinding as it is external facing, needs to interoperate and the client can't work with wsHttpBinding. This service receives all incoming method calls and forwards them onto another service. This other service is internal and uses netTcpBinding.

The problem is I am getting the following error:

Addressing Version 'AddressingNone (http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none)' does not support adding WS-Addressing headers.

Now, I am not entirely sure, but I am assuming this is something to do with the messages coming in as SOAP 1.1 but the netTcpBinding is using SOAP 1.2 and there is a mismatch? If so, how do I work around this? If not, any ideas what else it could be?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to explicitly copy the message into the right message version and then forward that on. You must also remember to copy the message back to the original version on the way back.

Comment: Could you please describe how it's possible to change message version?